# Display posts with specific meta value in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a function which display posts of a custom post type in wordpress:

Code:

```
<?php
 $args = array(
              'post_type' => 'todo_listing',
              'posts_per_page' => 4,
              'order' => 'asc',
              'meta_value' => '0'
              );
 $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
 ?>     

 <ul class="leftlist">

<?php
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>

        <li class="todo" id="<?php echo get_the_ID();?>" itemage="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'_todotime',true)?>"><a href="javascript:;"<?php if($all_meta_for_user[get_the_ID()][0]){               
        ?>
        class="strike"

    <?php
}
?>
       >           
  <?php if($all_meta_for_user[get_the_ID()][0]){?>
            <span class="check_box cb"></span>
            <?php }else{?>
        <span class="uncheck_box cb"></span>
        <?php }?>   
        <p><?php the_title(); ?></p></a>           
        <?php
        endwhile;
        ?>            
        </ul>
```

Which results in the HTML rendered as follows:

```
<li class="todo" id="1013" itemage=""><a href="javascript:;" class="">
    <span class="cb uncheck_box"></span>
    <p>Some Text here</p></a>
</li>
```

or

```
<li class="todo" id="1013" itemage=""><a href="javascript:;" class="">
    <span class="check_box"></span>
    <p>Some Text here</p></a>
</li>
```

If the class has `span class="cb uncheck_box"` the meta value is 0 and if the `span class="check_box"`, meta value is 1.

I only want to show those items with Meta Value 1. How can I modify the above wordpress function to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You only need to do a small change to your query and it should be all fixed.

```
$args = array(
              'post_type' => 'todo_listing',
              'posts_per_page' => 4,
              'order' => 'asc',
              'meta_query' => array(
                  array(
                      'key' => 'checkbox_meta',
                      'value' => '1',
                      'compare' => 'IN',
                      )
                  )
              );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

That takes the key `checkbox_meta` and checks that it has a value of 1. If not then it doesn't get the data.

Therefore you should get the first 4 with the `checkbox_meta` set to 1.

Readmore: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters section `'orderby' with 'meta_value' and custom post type`

Comment: thanks that doesnt work as they key is not checkbox_meta but it is the id of the post. Any work around that?

Answer (score -2):

Here is the code you can use:

```
<?php
$args = array(
          'post_type' => 'todo_listing',
          'posts_per_page' => 4,
          'order' => 'asc',
          'meta_value' => '0'
          );
 $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
?>     

<?php
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
<?php if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'checkbox_meta', true) == 0) { ?>
<?php echo get_the_ID();?> <?php the_title(); ?>
<?php } ?>

<?php
endwhile;
?>
```

I think there is some detail that you have missed to give out but assuming the code `<?php echo get_the_ID();?> <?php the_title(); ?>` prints out the given html then I suppose this could work. Get back to me if it couldn't be solved.

Comment: This is a bad idea. The user wants to show 4 posts. This will hide any that don't match of the 4 retrieved.

Comment: @ Prathik, thanks..I have edited the  php code above to show how the html is rendered

Comment: @NathanDawson OP had missed to show how html is rendered so I just wanted to show how he can differentiate between the posts with meta value 0 and 1. Thanks.